# Using residue theorem to calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^\frac12 (1+x^2)}$ get a different value from the value obtained by classical method

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to calculate the next integral by using residue theorem:
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^\frac12 (1+x^2)}.
$$
Let $f(z)=1/(z^\frac12(1+z^2))$ and $\varepsilon,R$ be any real number such that $0 < \varepsilon < 1 < R$. Choose the contour
\begin{align}
C_1&:z(t)=Re^{it}\quad(\theta \le t \le 2\pi-\theta)\\
C_2&:z(t)=t-i\varepsilon\quad(0\le t\le R\cos\theta) \\
C_3&:z(t)=\varepsilon e^{it}\quad(\frac\pi2\le t\le \frac{3\pi}2) \\
C_4&:z(t)=t+i\varepsilon\quad(0\le t\le R\cos\theta)
\end{align}
where $\theta= \arcsin\frac{\varepsilon}{R}$. By residue theorem
$$
\oint_{C_1-C_2-C_3+C_4}f(z)dz = 2\pi i\left( \operatorname{Res}(f,i) + \operatorname{Res}(f,-i)\right).
$$
Here
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}(f,i) &= \lim_{z\to i}\frac{z-i}{z^\frac12 (1+z^2)} = \lim_{z\to i}\frac1{z^\frac12(z+i)} = \frac{1}{2i\cdot i^\frac12} = \frac{-1-i}{2\sqrt 2}, \\
\operatorname{Res}(f,-i)&= \lim_{z\to -i}\frac{z+i}{z^\frac12 (1+z^2)} = \lim_{z\to i}\frac1{z^\frac12(z-i)} = \frac1{-2i\cdot(-i)^\frac12} = \frac{-1+i}{2\sqrt2}.
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\oint_{C_1-C_2-C_3+C_4}f(z)dz = -\frac{2\pi i}{\sqrt2}.
$$
It is easy to check $\int_{C_1}f(z)dz,\int_{C_3}f(z)dz\to 0\ (\varepsilon\to0,R\to\infty)$. And since $\exp(-\frac12(\ln|z|+i(\arg z+2\pi))) = -1/\sqrt z$ it obtains
$$
\lim_{\substack{\varepsilon\to0\\R\to\infty}}\int_{C_4}f(z)dz = -\lim_{\substack{\varepsilon\to0\\R\to\infty}}\int_{C_2}f(z)dz = \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^\frac12 (1+x^2)}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^\frac12 (1+x^2)} = -\frac{\pi i}{\sqrt2}.
$$
It is very curious that the integration of a real positive-valued function become a imaginary number. In fact, by using classical method, the integration will be $\pi/\sqrt2$, which seems to be the true answer.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: First, you seem to have taken the principal values (i.e., on the principal branch) of the square roots there. Second, you don't show your actual calculations and your contour is hard for me to understand, mainly the definition of $\;\theta\;$as...arcsine? I'm not saying there is a mistake there, it is just I don't understand it: why that contour? In fact, I can't even picture it in my mind...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I assumed the argument is in $(0,2\pi)$. Is there any mistake? For the secound question, I draw the contour: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ar4ma4cbgy . This contour is useful to calculate $\int_0^\infty \sqrt x/(1+x^2) dx$, which has the same branch point and poles as this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of the contour and the analysis are all perfect, but you made a slippery mistake, because with the contour comes the deffinition of the principal argument:

$$0\leq \arg(z)<2\pi$$

And the residue of $-i$ isn't calculated propperly in your work.

Notice that with this deffinition:

$$\arg(-i)=\frac{3 \pi}{2}$$

then:
$$\sqrt{-i} = e^{\frac{1}{2} (ln|-i|+i \arg{(-i)})} = e^{i \frac{3\pi}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} (-1+i)$$

Then, if you do the rest of the calculation,

$$\text{Res}(f,-i) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(1-i)$$

Then if you apply the Residue Theorem:

$$2\pi i \left[\text{Res}(f,i)+ \text{Res}(f,-i) \right]=2\pi i \left[-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(1+i)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(1-i)\right] = 2\pi i \left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i\right] = \frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Therefore, your real-valued integral is real and matches the answer you were given to check.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't realize the choice of branch also affects residue. Thank you.